# How do I make the number appear at the top of the line in a numbered list

Tags: google-docs

How do I make the number in a numbered list appear at the top of the "line" if I for instance paste an image into it?

If you have a look at the image below, I want the number to appear where the arrow is pointing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is not exactly what you're looking for, but the closest I could come to this was by reducing the line spacing in the list and then adding a blank line after the bullet item, with the results as shown below.

[image]

In case you do want to replicate this, you'll just go to the line spacing menu, and then change the "List item spacing, Before" field to something small, or zero:

[image: List Item Spacing Menu]

I used a value of zero in the above example.

[image: List Item Spacing Dialog]

Comment: Well, it certainly is a workaround, and I might go for it if nothing else shows up. However, I feel like this is functionality which should be in the app, though that could just be me being overly optimistic ^_^